# how to use onSaveInstanceState button that change the background layout?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android develop. i just stated this week.
i dont know if im asking stupid question but i want to learn.
i have created an app just click a button change the background color.
my layout is this

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.seluhadu.colorpicker.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="136dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="52dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and i have a class "java" like this

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    Integer[] colors = {
            R.color.color1,
            R.color.color2,
            R.color.color3,
            R.color.color4,
            R.color.color5,
            R.color.color6,
            R.color.color7,
            R.color.color8,
            R.color.color9,
            R.color.color10,
            R.color.color11,
            R.color.color12,
            R.color.color13,
            R.color.color14,
            R.color.color15,
            R.color.color16,
            R.color.color17,
            R.color.color18,
            R.color.color19,
            R.color.color20
    };

    Random random;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         random = new Random();
         relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.background);
         button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),
                 colors[random.nextInt(colors.length)]));
            }
        });
        }
```

it just change the background color random.
when it change the color if i rotat the screen it change to default back.
my question is how to make a onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState method to save the change color even if i reopen the app to stay the color that i change.
OR how can i do like that in other way?

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

> When your activity is recreated after it was previously destroyed, you can recover your saved state from the Bundle that the system
>   passes your activity. Both the onCreate() and onRestoreInstanceState()
>   callback methods receive the same Bundle that contains the instance
>   state information.
>
> Because the onCreate() method is called whether the system is creating
>   a new instance of your activity or recreating a previous one, you must
>   check whether the state Bundle is null before you attempt to read it.
>   If it is null, then the system is creating a new instance of the
>   activity, instead of restoring a previous one that was destroyed.

```
     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        Button button;
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
        Integer[] colors = {
                R.color.color1,
                R.color.color2,
                R.color.color3,
                R.color.color4,
                R.color.color5,
                R.color.color6,
                R.color.color7,
                R.color.color8,
                R.color.color9,
                R.color.color10,
                R.color.color11,
                R.color.color12,
                R.color.color13,
                R.color.color14,
                R.color.color15,
                R.color.color16,
                R.color.color17,
                R.color.color18,
                R.color.color19,
                R.color.color20
        };

        Random random;
        Boolean backgroundChanged = false;
        int colorIndex;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            // Check whether we're recreating a previously destroyed instance
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                // Restore background color from saved state
                backgroundChanged = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("backgroundChanged", false);
                colorIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt(colorIndex, 0);  
            } 
            random = new Random();
            relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.background);


 if(backgroundChanged) {
    relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), colors[colorIndex]));
            }   
            button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                backgroundChanged = true;
                colorIndex = random.nextInt(colors.length);
                relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), colors[colorIndex]));
            }
        });
        }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        savedInstanceState.putBoolean("backgroundChanged", backgroundChanged);
        if(backgroundChanged) {
            savedInstanceState.putInt("colorIndex", colorIndex);
        }
        // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

Comment: it worked when it is onPause. when it is onDestroy it change back.

Comment: For that use SharedPreferences as in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Update

Here's my code below, plugged into your posted example:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    random = new Random();

    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.background);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", 0);
    int colorIndex = settings.getInt("colorIndex", 0);
    updateBackground(colorIndex);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int colorIndex = random.nextInt(colors.length);
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", 0);
            settings.edit().putInt("colorIndex", colorIndex).apply();
            updateBackground(colorIndex);
        }
    });
}

private void updateBackground(int colorIndex) {
    relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), colors[colorIndex]));
}
```

---

If you have to store the color even through app restarts, you should use `SharedPreferences` instead of using `onSaveInstanceState()`.

In your `onClick()`, when you generate the random index for your color array, write that value to your `SharedPreferences` object. In `onCreate()` when you set everything up, read the value out of the `SharedPreferences`.

To write:

```
int colorIndex = random.nextInt(colors.length);
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", 0);
settings.edit().putInt("colorIndex", colorIndex).apply();
```

To read:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", 0);
int colorIndex = settings.getInt("colorIndex", 0);
```